# Short story with scientist seeking spiders. They trap him in a hole which is filling with water

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this in middle school approx. 35 years ago. 
Looking for a short story about a scientist from a museum who falls into a hole and gets trapped while looking for rare giant spiders. It was in a jungle setting possibly So. america. 
The spiders returned to the hole (their home base? and crawled all over him especially when it started to rain and the hole filled up with water.   He eventually is able to burrow or tunnel out of the hole. 
.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details that you remember? Every little bit helps us.

Comment: this is a longshot - [Death Traps of FX-31](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/29309/29309-h/29309-h.htm), Astounding Stories, 1933.

Answer (score 4):

"[The Bamboo Trap](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1710382)" by Robert Lemmon in 1923, just hit up my old english teacher. It's available in *[O. Henry Memorial Award Prize Stories of 1923](https://archive.org/stream/ohenrymemorialaw00unse_28/#page/120/mode/2up/)*

> "The Bamboo Trap" illustrates the struggle of the American scientist far afield. John Mather's adventure in the
> Andes, wherein his problem is to escape from a hole in the
> mountain side is enlivened by spiders. He escapes through a
> gallant physical fight. It is impossible to resist reference to
> a suggestion made by a reader of this story, a reader who is
> avowedly of the camp preferring Russian to American
> fiction. This tale would be more life-like, he said, if it ended
> on the unfinished struggle. "Why have that flood tear
> down the remaining barrier? Accident, wasn't it?" But
> if Mather had not very nearly destroyed the barrier, accident would have availed him nothing. An Oriental in that trap doubtless would have concluded, "If I am fated to die
> I shall die." Therein is exemplified the difference between
> the philosophy in literature of the negative and philosophy
> in literature of the positive.

A quote from the story:

> Then it rained. The heavens opened and crashed down.
> A torrent of mud and water poured through the cave roof,
> ripping the opening to twice its former size. Like a huge
> bucket the cave caught and held the flood. Momentarily
> the water rose — to Mather's ankles, his knees, his waist.
> The spiders struggled in it, dropping from walls and roof by
> dozens. They swarmed over him horribly as they fought
> with each other for safety on his body and head. He tried
> to brush them off, to drown them by sousing himself under
> the cascade that spilled down from above, but they clung to
> him like leeches.

> The water was up to his chest, now. Presently he was
> swimming, his head a mass of spiders that thickened by the
> minute and nearly suffocated him. For an age he struggled,
> growing weaker and weaker, knowing that in the end he must
> sink under that chaotic mass. The thought of it nerved
> him to a few more feeble strokes, a final effort to rid his head
> of the clammy bodies. Then, miraculously, a clatter and
> splash of falling rocks and earth, a sucking sound as from
> a giant sluice pipe suddenly cleared, and his feet touched
> bottom.

Comment: Can you explain why this matches?

Comment: http://section244.blogspot.com/2009/10/great-short-stories-61-70.html might be useful.

Comment: Text available in https://archive.org/stream/ohenrymemorialaw00unse_28/#mode/2up